# Dismiss View Controller on Appear, without displaying it

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller. I have a flag called: "dismissOnAppear". basically if this flag is set to YES, I want to Dismiss my view controller as soon as the app returns to it.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(self.dismissOnApear)
    {
         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

The problem is that the view is appearing for a split second and then dismissing. Is there a way I can dismiss the view controller when I return to it, without it displaying for a split second?

Edit: For more context:

I have ViewControllers A, B And C. A present B, then B present C. I want to return to A when I close C, and not to B. The views are presented modally, doing it through navigation controller and push is not an option now, so is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely you want to set up your classes and app structure a bit differently, as this seems a hacky way to achieve something that can be done properly. Could you give a little more context as to why you want to show a viewController and then not actually show it? Is there some stuff happening in viewDidLoad for example that should be in its own class / structure? Also note that what you are doing only works when the viewController is presented, not when it is displayed for example in a UINavigationController.

Comment: @Joride thanks for your comment, added an edit to my questions

Comment: A>B>C, now from C you want to come on A?

Comment: @Alok yes I want to return to A (not create a new instance of A)

Comment: wait you are talking about modally presenting and dismissing, not UiNavigationControler push/pop??

Comment: i have added another answer please analyse and implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the presenting controllers until you reach the parent, and dismiss the view from there.

```
UIViewController *vc = self.presentingViewController;
    while (vc.presentingViewController) {
        vc = vc.presentingViewController;
    }
    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Although it works, this is not a scalable solution. Using kludges like this indicates poor structure of an application, and will come back to bite you when the app evolves when it gets more and more succesfull. If the app is maintained by just you, you can get away with this.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this. In C view controller class call this method when you want (example button click or whatever ever):

```
- (void)turnBackToAViewController{

for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {

    //Do not forget to import AViewController.h
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[AViewController class]]) { 

        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                              animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am not using a navigation controller, I am presenting the view modaly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easies way would be to use a UINAvigationController, but that seems not an option. If the reason to avoid the navigationController is because you want your won animations, you can still use navigationController, and use custom transitions (see the UINavigationControllerDelegate method:

```
- (nullable id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Another way is to implement your own containerViewController with a similar interface as a UINavigatioController, which handles exactly what you want (as you write the code for it). In order to achieve this, you need to know about parent and childviewController, and checkout Apple's containerViewController guide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Can you explain why it is you do now want to use a UINavigationController?

Comment: I can't use navigation controller because I would have to refactor a big piece of code, especially the transition animation is very complex, and it was done for a modal transition.

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe just keep a weak reference in C to ViewController A and tell VC A to dismiss the currently presented viewController (which is B, so it might take C along with it).

Answer (score 0):

1.Make a public property in CViewController as:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) BViewController *bViewController;//please import BViewController//must be **weak**(avoid retain cycle)
```

2.When you show CViewController from BViewController

```
CViewControllerObj.bViewController = self;
```

3.Now when you are in CViewController cal this:

```
- (void)turnBackToAViewController{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    [self.bViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

    }];

}];
}
```

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's seamless dismissing animation for structure `A>B>C` with two modal view controllers.

In order to hide `B` controller when dismissing both `B` and `C` controllers, make a snapshot view of `C` controller when presenting it (in `B` controller) and display it:

```
[self presentViewController:cViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    UIView *snapshotView = [cViewController.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:snapshotView];
}];
```

Then, when you need to dismiss both controllers (in `C` controller) just call this method on `C` controller:

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

It will display `B` controller shortly, but don't worry we already hide it under `C` controller snapshot :)